# A Sequence converges to a limit $L \in \mathbb R$ if, and only if, an $N$-th tail of the sequences converges to $L$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

I want to show that a sequence $(a_n:n \in \mathbb N)$ converges to a limit $L \in \mathbb R$ if, and only if, an N-th tail of the sequences converges to $L$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$. For each $N \in \mathbb N$, an N-th tail sequence can be defined as $(t_n:n \in \mathbb N)$ where $t_n := a_{N+n}$.

Using the definition of a limit for the sequence $(a_n:n \in \mathbb N)$, we have the following:

For every $0 \lt \epsilon$, there is a natural number $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $N_{\epsilon} \lt n$, $|a_n - L| \lt \epsilon$. But I'm not sure what to do next in order to show that the $N$-th tail converges. Which natural number should I choose for the $N$-tail? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- If $a_n$ converges to $L$, then $N = 0$ works.
- If an $N$-th tail converges to $L$, then $t_n \rightarrow L$, i.e. for any $\varepsilon > 0$, $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n > K$ yields $|t_n - L| \leq \varepsilon$ or $|a_{N+n} - L| \leq \varepsilon$.
  So for any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $M = K + N$, if $p > M$, then 
  $|a_{p} - L | \leq \varepsilon$ (because, for $p > M$, we write $p = N + n$ with $n > K$).

Comment: I think though that $N$ has to be a natural number, meaning that it can only be a positive integer and not be equal to zero.

Comment: If $a_n$ converges to $L$, then $a_{n+1}$ converges also to $L$. Then take $N = 1$.